# Scope nested model with ancestry gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, scope, ancestry

I use two models:

**Productgroup**

```
has_ancestry 
has_many :products
```

**Product**

```
belongs_to :productgroup
```

The product model is using the attribute "active".

Now I would like to scope the Productgroup model to get only productgroups with active products. There may be root productgroups with no products but with childs that have active products. So I'm looking for something like this:

```
@productgroups = Productgroup.includes(:products).where("productgroups.children.products.active IS ?", true)
```

Does anyone has an idea how to do this?

Comment: Try this `@productgroups = Productgroup.includes(:products=> {:active => true})`

Comment: @Pardeep Dhingra, thanks, but this does not include productgroups where the children have active products.